# Three beeps and then nothing?

Tags: shutdown

My sister was using her computer just like she does everyday before the screen suddenly went black and she couldn't do anything. She then held the power button down to shut it off completely, because the lights in the front were still on. After waiting a few minutes, she tried to turn it back on, only to have her computer beep three times at her. 
She's really freaking out, so I would appreciate any help you could give.

Comment: Figure out who the BIOS manufacturer is for her computer, then go to their website and look up their beep codes.

Comment: What model computer is this?

Answer (score 1):

the meaning of the beeps depends on the motherboard of the computer. Check your manual, or find it online. It'll be in there.

Answer (score 1):

This page explains the meaning of [error code beeps](http://www.pchell.com/hardware/beepcodes.shtml) for different systems.

Sounds like either the video or memory went bad. Maybe even something else on the motherboard. Here's some simple diagnostic tips if you don't have any advanced tools.

1. Power off and unplug computer
2. Open up pc case to look inside. Make sure all connections fit tight where they're supposed to be and don't look fried or otherwise damaged. Try and look at the different components on the motherboard to see if anything looks fried or damaged. Sometimes cheap capacitors will leak and I once had a diode with a fried and broken lead. Some motherboards have LED lights or an LED display that might show additional information.
3. Make sure the fan on top of the CPU is spinning as well as the fan on the power supply.
4. If everything looks fine remove the memory and try to see if the computer will power up and show the bios screen. If it does, then the memory is bad. If there is more than one memory stick power off, install one memory stick, power on and see if it works. Repeat for the other sticks maybe you can identify a bad one. Finally try all the memory again making sure they're installed properly. You can also try cleaning the gold contacts with a pencil eraser if they look dull. Sometimes one might not have been seated right and came loose. Very rare but happens.
5. If the monitor plugs into a port that's in a separate card (not using onboard video) power off, remove the card and plug the monitor into the onboard video port if available and see if that works.
6. If still no dice... Unplug all the peripherals that are attached to the motherboard with the power off. If the computer powers up and shows the bios screen. Power off, plug something in like a disk drive, then power back up. If it comes up, power off, plug something else in and power on. Keep going until you find what might be bad.

If none of that helps and she feels comfortable removing the CPU I would try that next. With the power off (obviously) remove the CPU heatsink and fan, remove the CPU and see if it powers up. If it does the CPU is bad. It needs to be replaced and the new one installed properly with an appropriate cooler and thermal paste. If the CPU was good and you reinstall it on a new motherboard, you need to clean off the old paste on the top of the CPU package and bottom of the heatsink. It's usually a grey colored circle. I put the CPU some place secure like the bubble pack it comes in or just leave it in the CPU socket... pour some alcohol on a paper coffee filter and gently rub it clean. Don't soak the filter, just get it damp. Blow off any dust before applying thermal paste and reinstalling the heatsink/fan.

My guess is it's probably the memory or something on the motherboard. If you live in an area of the world it's winter now, I've seen motherboards fry when they've been placed too close to radiators on very cold days.